# Php error on simple mail script

Tags: php, html, email

Please send help I'm really bad at coding  and I have to present my website as a presentation tomorrow (in like 7 hours, it's 2pm right now)
http://theomarkus.site90.net/contact.php displays an error when entering details
http://puu.sh/95nto/931082b373.png
I have pasted the problematic php in full

```
    <?php
// Contact Form - http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();        // starts session, if not already started
if(!headers_sent()) header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');            // sets header for UITF-8 encoding

/** HERE ADD YOUR DATA **/

$cmail['to'] = 'theomarkus@gmail.com';          // Receiver e-mail address (to which the email will be send)

// If you want to use the SMTP server from GMail, set the value 1 at GMAIL constant
// Add your GMail address at the GMAIL_USER, and add the password for this e-mail at GMAIL_PASS
// If you want to use the local mail server, let GMAIL to 0
define('GMAIL', 1);
define('GMAIL_USER', 'BLANKED');
define('GMAIL_PASS', 'BLANKED');

      /* From here no need to modify */

// Check the anti-spamm code
if(isset($_POST['anti_spam']) && isset($_POST['anti_spam1']) && $_POST['anti_spam']==$_POST['anti_spam1']) {
  // Check if all necessary data are received by post
  if(isset($_POST['nume']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    // removes external whitespace and tags
    $_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);
    $_POST = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST);

    // gets form data
    $cmail['nume'] = $_POST['nume'];
    $cmail['from'] = $_POST['email'];
    $cmail['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];
    $cmail['body'] = 'E-mail from Contact form, sent by: '. $cmail['nume'] ."\n His /Her e-mail address: ". $cmail['from']. "\n IP: ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. "\n\n"
      .'message: '. $_POST['message']; 

    // include the class that sends the email
    include('sendmail/class.sendemail.php');

    // create an object of sendEMail class that sends the email
    $obEMail = new sendEMail($cmail);
    $re = $obEMail->re;
  }
  else $re = 'Error: not all form fields.';
}
else $re = 'Error: Incorrect verification code.';

echo $re;           // output the resulted message
```

Comment: http://puu.sh/95nto/931082b373.png right there

Comment: @user3685497 Very few user on SO will click links to servers/domains they don't trust or recognize, even if it is only a PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem come from here :

```
include('sendmail/class.sendemail.php');
```

Are you sure this is the right path ?

Comment: It is indeed the wrong path but i have no idea what it's supposed to find a path to

Comment: I suppose you found the code on internet. If yes, there may be a file name class.sendmail.php where you found it. Download it and put it in sendmail/class.sendemail.php. In this file, there is the class sendEMail you're using for send the mail.

Comment: If you took it from http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/contact-form-php-ajax-script_s2, the file you need is in the .zip.

Answer (score 0):

Either class.sendemail.php is misspelled and it needs to be include('sendmail/class.sendmail.php')  or the class.sendmail/class.sendmail.php is not in your path.

If not in your path the easiest thing to do might be to try something like:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sendmail/class.sendmail.php';
```

Comment: It's not going to work because `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sendmail/class.sendmail.php';` is the same as `include('sendmail/class.sendemail.php');`

Comment: Hmm  maybe he can add the location of the file to his path then: set_include_path('/path/to/file');